# I2S support on imx7d development board

Tags: audio, android-things

Does the current version of Android Things OS support i2s audio with the imx7d development board? I couldn’t find it in the PIO list.

Comment: Yes, it does as per the [list of supported hardware](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html#hardware_platforms) and [imx7d PIO](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d).

Answer (score 1):

The I2S audio routes are not exposed through the Peripheral I/O API. Instead, you can direct audio output to the I2S bus by selecting the route from the `AudioManager`.

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
AudioDeviceInfo[] devices = manager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);
```

The device interface where `getType()` returns `AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUS` is the I2S bus. You can see this method being used in the [Google Assistant sample](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant) to select the audio route.